# How to register existing UWP app with Microsoft App Registration Portal

Tags: uwp, azure-active-directory, onedrive

I had a UWP app working with OneDrive, allowing users to read and write to a file.

Then I accidentally deleted my app from the Application Registration Portal (https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList) and now any OneDrive related code throws an authentication error.

I am able to add a new app but then unable to add 'Windows Store' as a platform.

[Here is a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXIam.png)

How can I re-register my app with the Registration Portal to get it working with OneDrive again?

Here is the code I'm using to authenticate:

```
var msaAuthenticationProvider = new OnlineIdAuthenticationProvider(new string[] { "onedrive.readwrite" });
        await msaAuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateUserAsync();
        client = new OneDriveClient("https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0", msaAuthenticationProvider);
```

Here is the error I am currently getting when my I run the code above:

```
The application requesting authentication tokens is either disabled or incorrectly configured. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80860003)
```

Thanks for any help anyone can offer!

Comment: Current portal have 2 type of apps - Converged and Live SDK app group. To use the platform - Windows Store, you should choose the "Live SDK" app group.

Comment: I have added a Live SDK app as you suggested but the only options I have when adding a platform is "web" and "native". How can I add "Windows Store"?

Comment: Sorry, I've misunderstood your situation. And I have no idea for the case - accidental removal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to thread : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f4fac43f-3baa-4c3f-9363-b0062bf20af3/relink-application-in-live-services?forum=wpsubmit

> > After some diagnosis and discussion, as far as I known once we have deleted app in the live services which has associated with a Windows Store App, it is not possible to re-link it, what we can do is to create a new Windows Store App in the Dashboard.